# Why is this code not working, cmd calling paint

Tags: shell, cmd

I wanted to open an image in paint that was in a subfolder, why did these commands all not work?

```
C:\Users\user>mspaint C:/Users/user/tempo/screenshot_Nov082017165434.jpg

C:\Users\user>mspaint C:/Users/user/tempo/screenshot_Nov082017165434.jpg

C:\Users\user>mspaint /tempo/screenshot_Nov082017165434.jpg

C:\Users\user>mspaint \tempo\screenshot_Nov082017165434.jpg
```

I always got an error saying that te file would not exist, but it does, doublechecked it twice!

Where is my error? :/

Comment: This is not really about programming, so it seems off topic. Anyway, `\tempo\screenshot_Nov082017165434.jpg` won't work; `tempo` is not the root folder of the drive you're currently in. And just telling us the files exist is not much use without evidence of that: a screenshot of them in Windows Explorer with the full path visible, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the forward slashes (/), but it is expecting a path with backslashes ().

Try this :

```
C:\Users\user>mspaint C:\Users\user\tempo\screenshot_Nov082017165434.jpg
```

Comment: I tested this with an image on my machine that definitely existed, and using forward slashes also worked OK. So I don't think this is the problem. (Using forward slashes is not idiomatic, though.)

Comment: @underscore_d: it's well known that it works. That's no reason to use wrong syntax.

Comment: You might want to read my comment again, especially that bit in parentheses at the end, which was intended to avoid nitpicking, but hey. My point is that this does not answer the question. It may indicate a style correction to the code, but that only justifies a comment at best, unless the "wrong syntax" is proven to actually be wrong in any functional sense.

Comment: Using forward slashes in the parameter of mspaint.exe is not working on my side (cmd.exe - version 10.0.16299.19). I agree that Windows handle correctly forward and backward slashes **for the application path**. But, concerning the **given parameters**, this is left to the application, which can or can't handle correctly the slashes. In this case, it seems that mspaint does not handle correctly the forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

it's working fine with the sub folder and even with the different directory.

try this.
[image]